# PostgreSQL: Forward fill NULL values with previous NOT NULL value in group

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying fill `NULL` values in multiple columns (different column types INT, VARCHAR) with previous `NOT NULL` value in a group ordered by date. Considering following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
   id VARCHAR,
   date DATE,
   value_1 INT,
   value_2 VARCHAR
);


INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(1, '2022-01-04', 5, 'asdf'),
(1, '2022-01-03', NULL, NULL),
(1, '2022-01-02', NULL, 'def'),
(1, '2022-01-01', 4, NULL),
(2, '2022-01-04', 1, 'a'),
(2, '2022-01-03', NULL, NULL),
(2, '2022-01-02', 2, 'b'),
(2, '2022-01-01', NULL, NULL);
```

[image]

I want to get here (please consider value_1 --> INTEGER, value_2 string):

[image]

Comment: You said you want to set null values with previous values. So, why does `value_1` end up being 4 for 2022-01-02 and 2022-01-03 instead of 5? After all, `value_1` was 5 for 2022-01-01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One day, PostgreSQL may support the `IGNORE NULLS` option for `LEAD` and `LAG` functions.

In the mean time, you must use window functions to build groups, then select the maximum in each group.

```
SELECT id, date,
       MAX(value_1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp_1) AS value_1,
       MAX(value_2) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp_2) AS value_2
FROM(
    SELECT *,
          COUNT(value_1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date DESC) as grp_1,
          COUNT(value_2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date DESC) as grp_2
    FROM test
) T
ORDER BY ID, date
```

---

Explanation:

`COUNT(value_1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date ASC/DESC)` is a cumulative count that only increases when `value_1` is not null. The result is, for each consecutive value it takes (`1`, `2`, `3`), there will be 1 record where `value_1` is not null, and 0, 1 or several records where the field is null.

Example:

1. First record encountered (following the `ORDER BY Date` specified in the window);
   `value_1 is null` => `count` is 0.
2. Next record, `value_1 is not null` => `count` is 1.
3. Next record, `value_1 is null` => `count` stays at 1.
4. Next record, `value_1 is null` => `count` stays at 1.
5. Next record, `value_1 is not null` => `count` is 2.
   ... and so on.

Using this pattern, the `MAX(value_1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp_1)` works on  this partition of record by taking the non-null value out of each group.

1. Group `[count = 0]` has only 1 record with `null` => The `max` is null.
2. Group `[count = 1]` has 1 non null and 2 null values => The `max` is the non null value.
3. Group `[count = 2]` has 1 non null value (and an unspecified number of null values) => The `max` is the non null value.

The pattern keeps going; for every value of `count` (except `0`), the `max` window function always has exactly 1 non null value to pick.

---

Edit:
The above query is the answer to the original version of the question. Now that dates have been changed to be in the exact opposite order as before, the 3 occurrences of `ORDER BY date` must all be inverted to match. Basically, 2 negatives make a positive.

```
SELECT id, date,
       MAX(value_1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp_1) AS value_1,
       MAX(value_2) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp_2) AS value_2
FROM(
    SELECT *,
          COUNT(value_1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date ASC) as grp_1,
          COUNT(value_2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date ASC) as grp_2
    FROM test
) T
ORDER BY ID, date DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Short `window-functions` alternative: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mjQvoZuf)

```sql
SELECT 
  id
, date
,(JSONB_AGG(value_1)FILTER(WHERE value_1 IS NOT NULL)OVER w->>-1)::int AS value_1
, JSONB_AGG(value_2)FILTER(WHERE value_2 IS NOT NULL)OVER w->>-1    AS    value_2
FROM test
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) 
ORDER BY id, date DESC;
```

The principle remains the same as in [Lukasz'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75632948/5298879) and [Atmo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75462608/5298879) answers: it constructs a frame looking back at `value_N`s from previous dates for the same ID, gets rid of `NULL`'s then picks the latest non-`NULL`.

It's just shortened and cleaned up by having:

1. The [window defined once](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW) and re-used.
2. An [aggregate filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), to skip `NULL`s instead of collecting and having to remove them.
3. A [`jsonb` array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.12.1.2.1). Unlike a regular array it allows for [negative subscripting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE), eliminating the need for a subquery, a CTE or duplicating the code in order to call `array_upper()` and get the last element. That's at the price of having to cast non-`text` types.

   Negative index is equal to positive on a reversed array, so the same can be done with a regular array as long as its constructed in reverse, by inverting the frame clause and order: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NCcwUKwE)

Comment: I'm [posting this separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209) since it's fundamentally different from the approach I [initially suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75631505/5298879) - which I still somewhat prefer for it's conceptual simplicity, being a more direct translation of the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Using windowed function:

- `ARRAY_AGG` building array with defined order
- `ARRAY_REMOVE` removing NULLs
- getting the last item in the array (cte/or replicating entire query) - unfortunately no way to access it as `(array)[-1]`

Query version readable:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    ARRAY_REMOVE((ARRAY_AGG(value_1) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)), NULL) 
       AS value_1_arr,
    ARRAY_REMOVE((ARRAY_AGG(value_2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)), NULL) 
       AS value_2_arr
  FROM test
)
SELECT id, date,
    value_1_arr[array_upper(value_1_arr, 1)] AS value_1,
    value_2_arr[array_upper(value_2_arr, 1)] AS value_2
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, date DESC;
```

---

Debug (array_is_build, it is a matter of taking last item)

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    ARRAY_REMOVE((ARRAY_AGG(value_1) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)), NULL) 
       AS value_1_arr,
    ARRAY_REMOVE((ARRAY_AGG(value_2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)), NULL) 
       AS value_2_arr
  FROM test
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, date DESC;
```

[image]

---

Single query (lack of [-1] and duplicating the code makes it "ugly"

```
SELECT id, date,   
  (ARRAY_REMOVE((ARRAY_AGG(value_1) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)), NULL))
  [array_upper(ARRAY_REMOVE((ARRAY_AGG(value_1) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)), NULL),1)]
 AS value_1, 
  (ARRAY_REMOVE((ARRAY_AGG(value_2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)), NULL))
  [array_upper(ARRAY_REMOVE((ARRAY_AGG(value_2) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)), NULL),1)]
 AS value_2
FROM test
ORDER BY id, date DESC;
```

Output:

[image]

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZRrfG9aq)**

Comment: [It breaks](https://dbfiddle.uk/s04yg4Xz).

Comment: @Zegarek Thank you for extending the initial data set. The version with windowed `MAX` worked for OP's dataset but not in general. I have rewritten my answer and provided an `ARRAY_AGG` equivalent of `LEAD/LAG with IGNORE NULLS`

Comment: You have my upvote. After this I gave window functions a shot and ended up solving the subscript issue, if you mind taking a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75642951/5298879).

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) can help whenever your spec says you want one, top record in a group. You can use it in a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) in an update: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ToZ2AhaQ)

```sql
update test t1 
set value_1=(select distinct on (t2.id) value_1--The top value_1 (latest by date)
             from test t2                      --that's in the same table   ^
             where t2.date < t1.date           --in an earlier row          |
             and   t2.id   = t1.id             --for the same id            |
             and   t2.value_1 is not null      --and isn't a null.          |
             order by t2.id, date desc)        --The top meaning the latest_/
where t1.value_1 is null;
```

Since all it does is go to a row with a null and from its context, point back at a row you want to borrow the value from, it's fairly intuitive.