# Postgresql fill empty rows based on previous value

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, recursive-query

Start table:

```
year |  status
--------------
2018 | null
2019 | 1
2020 | null
2021 | null
2022 | 0
2023 | null
2024 | 1
2025 | null
```

I want to fill empty rows based on previous record value starting from the first null after first not null value

Expected result:

```
year |  status
--------------
2018 | null
2019 | 1
2020 | 1
2021 | 1
2022 | 0
2023 | 0
2024 | 1
2025 | 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL: Forward fill NULL values with previous NOT NULL value in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462304/postgresql-forward-fill-null-values-with-previous-not-null-value-in-group)

Comment: See this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073076/postgresql-fill-null-values-in-timeserie-query-with-previous-value