# Count number of raise by group from a history table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL structure :

```
CREATE TABLE history(
  entity_id INT,
  raise_number INT,
  assignedtogroup INT,
  time BIGINT
);
INSERT INTO history VALUES 
(1, 0, 435215, 1677235879584),
(1, null, 435215, 1677235879584),
(1, 1, null, 1678358448831),
(1, 2, null, 1678358851266),
(1, 3, null, 1678358861480),
(1, null, 2639656, 1678358930852),
(1, null, 2639656, 1678358930852),
(1, 4, null, 1678359050954),
(1, 5, null, 1678359059543);
```

I need to count the number of raise by group. If a group change, the next raise would be for that new group until a new group will be set. How can I select raise_number by group. In this case the expected output should be :

| entity_id | group | raise_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1435215 | 3 |
| 1 | 2639656 | 2 |

I came up using the following query :

```
SELECT entity_id, assignedtogroup AS group, 
       COUNT(*) AS raise_number
FROM (
  SELECT entity_id, assignedtogroup, raise_number,
         LAG(assignedtogroup) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id ORDER BY time) AS prev_group
  FROM history
) t
WHERE assignedtogroup IS NOT NULL AND (prev_group IS NULL OR prev_group = assignedtogroup)
GROUP BY assignedtogroup;
```

Output :

> Query Error: error: column "t.entity_id" must appear in the GROUP BY
> clause or be used in an aggregate function

How can I retreive the number of raise per group ?

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fcHarhr2smyooFKVvWvJ8T/7

Explanation :

The first 2 row indicate the current group `435215`.

Then we have 3 row which increment the raise number to 3 (raise linked to group `435215`).

After we change the group to 2639656.

As we changed the group, we count 2 raise (raise linked to group `2639656`).

Comment: Are you sure that `raise_number` for 2639656 is 2 (should be 5 I suppose)?

Comment: Yes 2639656 has 2 raise because the group has changed. It's now this group which have the next raise

Comment: Next raise_numbers after the change are 4 and 5?

Comment: the column `raise_number`  count the total of raise for the entity but not per group

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462304/postgresql-forward-fill-null-values-with-previous-not-null-value-in-group/75462608#75462608) help in any way? What I mean is: fill `assignedtogroup ` to the records that follow and once you are done, simply `COUNT(raise_number)... GROUP BY assignedtogroup`. I cannot come up with the query because I have not understand where your expected result comes from....

Comment: How can I apply it to my SQL structure ?

Comment: Let me try to answer your question, then if it is wrong, you tell me the piece of logic I missed. I just don't understand why the very first column (`raise_number = 0`) does not seem to count in your expected result. 0 is **not** null.

Comment: The 0 initiate the value for my entity. I should call the table  `history` instead of `test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75462608), we forward fill the nulls with the previous `assignedtogroup` and simply count the non null `raise_number`.
Note: as mentioned in the comments `raise_number = 0` is an initial value and must be ignored in the count.

```
WITH ForwardFilled(filledgroup, raise_number) AS (
    SELECT MAX(assignedtogroup) OVER (PARTITION BY grp), raise_number
    FROM(
        SELECT raise_number, assignedtogroup,
              COUNT(assignedtogroup) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC)
        FROM test
    ) T(raise_number, assignedtogroup, grp)
)
SELECT filledGroup, COUNT(raise_number)
FROM ForwardFilled
WHERE raise_number <> 0
GROUP BY filledGroup
ORDER BY filledgroup
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the column `entity_id` in the result ?

Comment: Yes but it could potentially change how things get aggregated (not with the data from your question since it only contains 1). **In the CTE**, either you treat it the same way as `raise_number` or the same way as `assignedtogroup` (follow the link I posted in my answer, it was precisely about forward filling 2 fields, you). In both cases, I expect it will be treated the same way as `filledGroup` **in the main query**...... or you can choose not to bother with this and add a `join` to the main query to retrieve `entity_id` from a different path.

Comment: I don't think I could use a join because and I don't know how to link to the row

Comment: You have to edit your question with new `entity_id`s and expected result.

Comment: I edited the question as asked

Comment: You didn't get it....  with 1 being the only value in the `entity_id` column, how do you expect me to understand which record(s) is/are used to fill each cell of your expected result. Should it be aggregated as a `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`? Should it be inferred from the first record (`OVER (PARTITION BY assignedtogroup ORDER BY time)` for instance)? What you have to explain is: "what if the first 2 records have different `entity_id` values?" "What if the last 3 records have different `entity_id` values?" ... and other things of the same kind.